# R scrape a blog for Title, number of comments and 'likes'

Tags: facebook, r, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to use R to grab some information from a few blogs.  The data I'd like to grab is:

```
1) Date posted
2) Blog Post Title
3) Number of Comments
4) Number of Facebook likes.
```

This blog [here](http://www.jamesaltucher.com/) has all the fields I'm looking to collect.

Ideally I'd like a data frame that looks like this:

```
Post_Date      CommentCount       FB_Likes   Title
2012-12-05          1                 629      The James and Claudia Kripalu Workshop– The Daily Practice: Finding Success From Within
  ...              ...                ...          ...
```

Is there a way to do this in R?  It seems like something that might be doable with `RCurl` but I'm not too familiar with `html/xml/js/etc`.

So far this is what I have:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
xmlTreeParse(getURI("http://www.jamesaltucher.com"))
```

when I run this I get errors that the opening and closing brackets don't match.

NOTE: These are not my blogs so I don't have admin access to the blog or their FB account.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you be more specific? is there a blog you have in mind?  Maybe provide some sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to get facebook like. 
I am intersting to see a solution. I treat dates with gsub to get pretty format.

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url.link <- 'http://www.jamesaltucher.com/'
blog <- getURL(url.link)
blog          <- htmlParse(blog, encoding = "UTF-8")
titles  <- xpathSApply (blog ,"//*[@class='article']/h2/a",xmlValue)             ## titles
dates   <- xpathSApply (blog ,"//*[@class='article']/h2/span/text()",
             function(x) {
                 y <- gsub('.*on(.*)Post.*','\\1',xmlValue(x))
               }
             )
dates <- dates[dates != 'Posted by ']
```

Comment: I tried this answer. How do I then export the titles and dates into a CSV or Excel file?

Answer (score 1):

I've found [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to be pretty easy to work with for scraping web content. Below are a couple of articles that may help you.

- [web scraping example with XPath](http://www.r-bloggers.com/web-scraping-yahoo-search-page-via-xpath/)
- [XPath Guide](http://www.xquery.com/examples/xpath/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to upvote but someone downvoted. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to parse `Html` not `Xml` so use `htmlParse` which will attempt to handle badly formed html. Examples of some xpaths follow

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
blogdata<-htmlParse(getURI("http://www.jamesaltucher.com"))
postDetail<-xpathSApply(blogdata,'/*//span[@class=\"details\"]',xmlValue)
title<-xpathSApply(blogdata,'/*//h2/a',xmlValue)
```

I think it will be harder to get the facebook likes etc as the page seems to call a script to access these.