# R scrape a blog for keywords in content and title

Tags: r, curl, web-scraping

I want to do something similar as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728289/r-scrape-a-blog-for-title-number-of-comments-and-likes) using *R or any other similar software*.

The additional requirements I want is:

1. scrape for **keywords in the blogpost content**
2. and count their occurrences

For simplicity sake, let us assume the blog in question is also www.jamesaltucher.com

By keywords, I mean any words that are the usual words google ignores like, "the", "an", "a", "of", etc.

Please assume that the blogs are public and I do not have admin account.

By content, I mean the content inside the blog post itself. Not necessarily comments.

**UPDATE:**
Currently, I can extract all the blogpost urls from www.jamesaltucher.com/sitemap.xml

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url.link <- 'http://www.jamesaltucher.com/sitemap.xml'
blog <- getURL(url.link)
blog          <- htmlParse(blog, encoding = "UTF-8")
titles  <- xpathSApply (blog ,"//loc",xmlValue)             ## titles
```

This is the screenshot.

[image]

**My next step is to iterate through all the entries in `titles` and extract the content for keyword frequency counting.**

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: So post some code with the target of your chosen test website.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in Python and maybe you can combine Python script below in R using rpy or

```
scan(pipe("python scraper.py | cat"))
```

The most difficult part must be correctly get the content of the blog... If you simply do soup.text. you might get some source code of the blog instead of the real content. You need to correctly locate your content using HTML tags, id, class.. etc.

For more information, please refer to this page of [BeautifulSoup Search the tree](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree).

```
import urllib2
from collections import Counter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get the html page of your target blog
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://datafireball.com/'))
# first, you need to retrieve the content of the blog
content = soup.find("div", {"id":"content"}).text.encode('utf-8')
# second, you count the frequency
cnt = Counter(content.split())
# print out the result to verify it works
print cnt
```

The output looks like this:

```
Counter({'the': 73, 'to': 41, 'of': 34, 'is': 28, 'a': 27, 'R': 27, 'in': 24, 'you': 21, 'can': 17, 'and': 15, 'that': 13, 'it': 11, '<-': 10, 'read': 10, 'all': 9, 'data': 9, 'how': 9, 'will': 9, '$': 9, 'by': 9, 'into': 9, 'this': 8, 'on': 8, 'line': 8, 'with': 8, '1': 7, 'not': 7, 'which': 7, 'I': 7, 'model': 7, 'for': 7, 'install': 6, 'linear': 6, 'standard': 6, '>': 6, 'You': 6, 'be': 6, 'your': 6, ':': 6, 'Redhat': 5, '.entry-header': 5, 'use': 5, 'chr': 5, '.entry-meta': 5, '2013': 5, 'need': 5, 'note': 5, 'The': 5, 'do': 5, 'Leave': 5, 'datafireball': 5, '.entry-content': 5, '#post-##': 5, 'Python': 5, 'or': 5, 'but': 5, '\xe2\x80\x93': 5, 'row': 4, 'R-squared': 4, 'num': 4, 'are': 4, 'from': 4, 'October': 4, 'List': 4, 'then': 4, 'our': 4, '2': 4, '=': 4, 'find': 4, 'make': 4, 'command': 4, 'In': 4, 'R,': 4, 'some': 4, 'To': 4, 'file': 4, 'code': 3, 'very': 3, 'what': 3, '3.': 3, 'working': 3, 'write': 3, 'help': 3, 'fit': 3, 'actually': 3, '2.': 3, 'R.': 3, 'out': 3, 'squared': 3, 'x': 3, 'first': 3, 'script': 3, '1.': 3, 'Then': 3, '3': 3, 'import': 3, 'we': 3, '~': 3, 'parse': 3, 'result': 3, 'really': 3, 'page': 3, 'package': 3, 'there': 3, 'up': 3, 'an': 3, 'kinds': 3, 'As': 3, 'code,': 3, '-c': 2, '-y': 2, 'string': 2, 'every': 2, '"a"': 2, 'Python.': 2, 'current': 2, '10,': 2, 'here': 2, 'change': 2, 'makes': 2, 'few': 2, '6': 2, 'tell': 2, '98': 2, 'flag': 2, 'my': 2, 'indicates': 2, 'Coefficient': 2, '0.9693628': 2, 'product': 2, '"B"': 2, 'su': 2, 'What': 2, 'R-squared:': 2, 'Here': 2, 'python': 2, 'easily': 2, 'all,': 2, 'From': 2, 'print': 2, 'created': 2, 'could': 2, '*': 2, 'white': 2, 'x,': 2, 'kind': 2, 'seamlessly': 2, 'Package': 2, 'points': 2, 'Hadoop': 2, 'Note,': 2, 'one': 2, 'title': 2, 'only': 2, 'pretty': 2, 'get': 2, 'see': 2, 'closed': 2, 'connection.': 2, 'BeautifulSoup': 2, 'much': 2, 'look': 2, 'while': 2, 'if': 2, 'connection': 2, 'check': 2, 'python.exec(\xe2\x80\x9cprint': 2, 'uses': 2, 'datafireball.com': 2, 'well': 2, 'y': 2, 'If': 2, 'just': 2, 'However,': 2, 'directory,': 2, 'input': 2, 'using': 2, 'like': 2, '[1]': 2, 'back': 2, '/': 2, 'noise': 2, 'run': 2, 'power': 2, 'anything': 2, 'trying': 2, 'called': 2, 'as': 2, 'when': 2, '4.': 2, 'together': 2, 'at': 2, 'sometimes,': 1, 'Web': 1, 'existing': 1, 'arguments,': 1, 'BeautifulSoup(stream)': 1, 'Take': 1, '(which': 1, '[yes/no]\xe2\x80\x98': 1, 'whose': 1, 'calculate': 1, 'default,': 1, "{\xe2\x80\x98class\xe2\x80\x99:'site-description\xe2\x80\x99}).text.encode(\xe2\x80\x98utf-8\xe2\x80\xb2)": 1, 'Residual': 1, 'str_py_dict': 1, 'languages': 1, 'asking': 1, 'method=\xe2\x80\x9dpearson\xe2\x80\x9d)': 1, 'otherwise,': 1, '***': 1, 'level': 1, 'list': 1, 'leave': 1, 'guy': 1, 'refer': 1, 'Rscript!': 1, 'lm(formula': 1, 'Functions': 1, 'Stats': 1, '\xe2\x80\x98**\xe2\x80\x99': 1, 'else,': 1, 'data(iris)': 1, '3Q': 1, '27,': 1, 'range.': 1, 'object.': 1, '"A"': 1, '"(1,\'a\',': 1, 'R-core-devel': 1, 'Determination.)': 1, '+': 1, '4': 1, 'version': 1, 'tips': 1, 'satisfy': 1, '10)': 1, 'Combining': 1, "input<-file('stdin',": 1, 'datafireball.py': 1, 'objects': 1, 'python.load(\xe2\x80\x98/tmp/datafireball.py\xe2\x80\x99)': 1, 'write(result,': 1, '(JSON),': 1, 'Never\xc2\xa0Use': 1, 'error:': 1, '"[1,\'a\',': 1, 'commonly': 1, 'here,': 1, '{': 1, 'Pythonic': 1, 'divide': 1, "'rpm": 1, 'Correlation': 1, 'type.': 1, 'sys': 1, 'output,': 1, 'apply': 1, 'unit': 1, 'figure': 1, '0': 1, 'edit(data)': 1, '/user/bin/R': 1, 'going': 1, 'm1': 1, '\xe2\x80\x9cshebang\xe2\x80\x9d': 1, '0.9691': 1, '0.001': 1, 'flat': 1, 'started': 1, 'freedom': 1, 'line.': 1, 'screen.': 1, 'So': 1, 'work': 1, 'Actually,': 1, 'soup': 1, '-0.6669': 1, 'py_iris.keys()\xe2\x80\x9d)': 1, '0.9694,': 1, 'stream': 1, 'Min': 1, '0.1': 1, '<2e-16': 1, 'something': 1, 'want': 1, 'Signif.': 1, 'Coefficients:': 1, 'r^2': 1, 'means': 1, 'Also,': 1, 'utilize': 1, 'command"),': 1, 'parameter': 1, 'len(py_iris)\xe2\x80\x9d)': 1, 'information': 1, '(Move': 1, '\xe2\x80\x9cR\xe2\x80\x9d': 1, 'processed.': 1, '(References:\xc2\xa0Pearson': 1, 'lines': 1, 'happen.': 1, 'string/stdout()': 1, 'so': 1, 'correlation': 1, 'again.': 1, 'sd': 1, 'lm(y': 1, 'record.': 1, 'already': 1, 'through': 1, 'looks': 1, 'defination):': 1, 'type=\xe2\x80\x9do\xe2\x80\x9d,': 1, 'mentioned': 1, 'interpreter': 1, 'still': 1, 'set.seed(100)': 1, 'its': 1, 'readLines:': 1, 'Multiple': 1, '-Uvh': 1, 'degrees': 1, '0.0003613\xc2\xa0,': 1, '2,': 1, '<': 1, 'good': 1, 'computer\xe2\x80\x99s': 1, 'introduce': 1, 'they': 1, "u'Sepal.Width',": 1, 'cluster.': 1, 'name': 1, '"")': 1, 'fully': 1, 'above(sd=5).': 1, 'mode': 1, 'each': 1, 'found': 1, 'side': 1, 'soup.find(\xe2\x80\x98div\xe2\x80\x99,': 1, '(Pearson\xe2\x80\x99s': 1, 'doing': 1, 'series': 1, 'idea': 1, '\xe2\x80\x93\xc2\xa0stdin/stdout': 1, 'Which': 1, 'happen': 1, 'python.load()': 1, 'is:': 1, 'df': 1, 'Std.': 1, 'Residuals:': 1, 'matrix': 1, 'Very': 1, 'content': 1, 'time.': 1, 'install.': 1, 'got': 1, 'file()/file_test()/file.access()/file.remove()/file.copy()/file.exist()/file.info()/file.append()/file.symlink()/file.link()/file.path()/file.show()': 1, 'written': 1, 'This': 1, 'python.assign(PyObject,RObject)': 1, 'gap.': 1, 'base': 1, '$cat': 1, 'put': 1, 'testData': 1, 'python.exec("python': 1, 'definition': 1, 'str(python.get(str_py_tuple))': 1, 'length': 1, 'yum': 1, '\'B\']"': 1, 'go:': 1, 'stdout:': 1, '1Q': 1, 'There': 1, 'yourself': 1, '6.': 1, 'input\xe2\x80\x99': 1, 'says': 1, 'open': 1, 'RGui': 1, 'IDE': 1, 'plot(y': 1, '0.01': 1, 'system': 1, '0.05': 1, 'their': 1, 'Rstudio.': 1, 'perfectly': 1, 'Data': 1, '#!/usr/bin/Rscript': 1, 'gives': 1, 'x)': 1, 'str(python.get(str_py_list))': 1, 'Install': 1, 'Enterprise': 1, 'easier.': 1, 'from?': 1, "http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm'": 1, '10': 1, 'translate': 1, '1:': 1, 'r': 1, 'df)': 1, '\xe2\x80\x9cstdin\xe2\x80\x9d': 1, '\xe2\x80\x98standard': 1, 'stdin': 1, 'cases,': 1, 'bs4': 1, 'turned': 1, '-0.2093': 1, 'have': 1, 'cleaned': 1, 'Service),': 1, 'tells': 1, 'F-statistic:': 1, '-': 1, 'end,': 1, 'build': 1, 'deviation.': 1, 'order.': 1, 'sure': 1, 'node': 1, 'data.frame': 1, '55.684': 1, 'sum(m1$residuals^2)': 1, 'most': 1, 'curve.': 1, 'connected': 1, 'RPython': 1, 'see,': 1, 'extremely': 1, 'str_py_list': 1, 'request': 1, 'pipe': 1, 'col=\xe2\x80\x9dred\xe2\x80\x9d)': 1, '}': 1, '1.37592': 1, '1:100': 1, 'slope': 1, 'returned.': 1, '2.06135': 1, 'n=1)': 1, 'pride,': 1, 'Manager)': 1, 'abline(m1,': 1, "'yum": 1, 'sudo': 1, 'y,': 1, 'Pr(>|t|)': 1, 'list).': 1, '\xe2\x80\x98r\xe2\x80\x99': 1, 'x))': 1, 'Windows).': 1, 'Base': 1, 'readLines(input,': 1, 'main=\xe2\x80\x9dy': 1, 'beat': 1, 'str(python.get(str_py_dict))': 1, 'codes:': 1, 'cannot': 1, 'during': 1, 'description': 1, '0.506': 1, 'Linux).': 1, 'summary': 1, 'bad': 1, '6.4': 1, 'them.': 1, '\xe2\x80\x98Is': 1, 'where': 1, 'inside': 1, 'xinch': 1, 'package,': 1, 'decided': 1, '0.03544': 1, 'close': 1, 'into\xc2\xa0R': 1, '#': 1, 'Again,': 1, 'please': 1, 'opened': 1, 'pump': 1, 'determination(\xe5\x86\xb3\xe5\xae\x9a\xe7\xb3\xbb\xe6\x95\xb0),': 1, 'across': 1, '0,': 1, 'available': 1, 'sd=10\xe2\x80\xb3)': 1, 'R-dev..': 1, 'connection,': 1, 'answers': 1, 'interface': 1, 'packages': 1, 'come': 1, 'EPEL(Extra': 1, '26.1505': 1, 'conlusion,': 1, 'R),': 1, 'cov(x,': 1, 'way,': 1, 'delete': 1, 'comes': 1, 'library(\xe2\x80\x98rPython\xe2\x80\x99)': 1, '1+1}"': 1, 'point': 1, 'dataframe': 1, 'file=\xe2\x80\x9ddata\xe2\x80\x9d\xe2\x80\xa6),': 1, 'ETL': 1, 'there,': 1, 'R-core': 1, 'we\xe2\x80\x99ve': 1, "u'Petal.Width',": 1, 'basic': 1, 'line..': 1, 'empty': 1, 'life': 1, 'options.': 1, 'covariance': 1, 'posts,': 1, 'catch': 1, 'Estimate': 1, 'And': 1, 'Adjusted': 1, 'edit/vi/emacs/xemacs/xedit': 1, '1.97333': 1, 'summary(m1': 1, 'python.get': 1, 'value': 1, 'versa.': 1, 'write(x,': 1, 'loop': 1, 'Rscript': 1, 'Above': 1, 'n=1': 1, 'cluster': 1, 'rnorm(length(x),': 1, '1000,': 1, 'regression': 1, 'different': 1, 'flag.': 1, '(sd(x)*sd(y))': 1, '2.2e-16': 1, 'html': 1, 'inch': 1, 'mode,': 1, 'document': 1, 'used': 1, 'http': 1, '\xe2\x80\x98*\xe2\x80\x99': 1, 'moment': 1, 'datatypes': 1, 'Coefficient,': 1, 'object': 1, 'this(Wikipedia': 1, 'getwd()/write()/unlink()': 1, 'str_py_tuple': 1, '10.23': 1, 'sys.path.append(\xe2\x80\x98/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.2.1-py2.7.egg\xe2\x80\x99)': 1, 'squared\xe2\x80\x9d': 1, 'distribute': 1, '(record)': 1, 'computing.': 1, 'stored': 1, 'questions': 1, 'rule..': 1, 'yes': 1, 'case,': 1, 'C-level': 1, 'console': 1, 'combine': 1, 'easy': 1, '-22.6284': 1, '\xc2\xa0You': 1, "'r')": 1, 'smart': 1, 'Pearson': 1, '6.1186': 1, 'format': 1, 'know': 1, 'helpful': 1, 'OK': 1, '\xe2\x80\x9cR\xc2\xa0squared\xe2\x80\x9d': 1, 'Streaming': 1, '5.': 1, 't': 1, 'popular': 1, 'output': 1, 'yinch': 1, 'simple,': 1, 'often': 1, 'people': 1, 'successfully': 1, 'library': 1, 'Call:': 1, '"{1:2,': 1, 'duration': 1, "[u'Petal.Length',": 1, 'users': 1, 'happens': 1, 'stdin/stdout': 1, 'does': 1, 'urllib2.urlopen(\xe2\x80\x98http://datafireball.com/&#8217;)': 1, 'either': 1, 'process': 1, 'while(length(row)>0)': 1, 'post': 1, 'super': 1, "'a':'A',": 1, 'First': 1, 'here(clearly,': 1, '\xe2\x80\x98.\xe2\x80\x99': 1, 'comment,': 1, 'important': 1, 'B:': 1, 'RPM(Redhat': 1, 'Use': 1, 'own': 1, '0.667': 1, 'Bash,': 1, 'file:': 1, 'coefficient': 1, 'dataset': 1, 'determine': 1, 'python.assign(\xe2\x80\x98py_iris\xe2\x80\x99,': 1, '\xe2\x80\x9cR': 1, 'R-core,': 1, 'a:': 1, 'computer': 1, 'datasets.': 1, 'DF,': 1, 'question': 1, 'start': 1, '\xe2\x80\x9crt\xe2\x80\x9d': 1, 'low': 1, "'B':": 1, 'call': 1, 'November': 1, 'function': 1, 'urllib2,': 1, 'complete': 1, 'enough': 1, 'properly': 1, 'Error': 1, 'p-value:': 1, 'open,': 1, 'sum((y-mean(y))^2)': 1, 'embedded': 1, '\'B\')"': 1, 'functions,': 1, 'below': 1, '(Intercept)': 1, '0.9694': 1, 'on\xc2\xa0Redhat6': 1, 'organize': 1, 'Usually,': 1, 'distribution': 1, '(Amazon': 1, 'etc.': 1, 'plotting)': 1, 'interactive': 1, 'Squared': 1, 'single': 1, 'model.': 1, "u'Sepal.Length',": 1, '15,': 1, 'fill': 1, 'machine': 1, 'functions': 1, 'read.csv\xe2\x80\xa6etc.': 1, 'output.': 1, 'Read': 1, 'Max': 1, '3101': 1, "R-devel'": 1, '5': 1, 'nonsense\xe2\x80\xa6': 1, 'small.': 1, 'deviation': 1, "u'Species']": 1, 'Streaming.': 1, 'Median': 1, 'urllib2': 1, 'journey': 1, '\xe2\x80\xa6': 1, '-6.8113': 1, 'debian': 1, 'position.': 1, '\xe2\x80\x94': 1, 'vice': 1, '\xe2\x80\x99': 1, '\xe2\x80\x98': 1, '\xe2\x80\x98***\xe2\x80\x99': 1})
```

Comment: why do you need to pipe to `cat` ??

Answer (score 0):

In R, something like this will work for you:

```
out <- lapply(titles, function(url) {
  content <- getURL(url)
  content <- gsub("<.*?>", "",content)
  content <- gsub("[[:space:][:punct:][:digit:]]+", " ",content)
  content <- tolower(content)
  table(strsplit(content,' '))
})
```

The result is a list of tables, though you could have it just return the output of `strsplit` directly instead.

You'll probably have to go through and remove words you don't like (e.g., `if`, `the`, etc.) but to do that you'll need a complete dictionary of such words to remove.